# Application exit on backkey press

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, navigation, windows-phone

I have a question after searching please ignore if it is simple. i am using navigation in windows phone 7. i want to do that when my application start it check that which page is open or not. i tried following code :

```
void RootFrame_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Uri.ToString().Contains("/MainPage.xaml") == true)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;

        RootFrame.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
            {
                if (ans == true)
                    RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                else
                    RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("//Views/PersonalInfo.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            });
    }
    if (e.Uri.ToString().Contains("external") == true)
    {
        // 
    }
}
```

but when i try this code. it check the condition and goes to the page but when i press the back-key, my app close.
i tried this :

```
Loaded += (s, e) =>
{
    AppCheck(); // call my method
    // and some condtion   
}
```

it goes to the desired page, but on back-key press it again goes to the second page.
i also try this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) but onbackkey my app close.

thanks !

Comment: Next time, please be careful about formatting.. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: You also have // in your second `Navigate` call, is that a typo here or on your original code?

Comment: @ToniPetrina : no ! its a page path define in navigation.

Comment: What do you expect? If this is a first page than on Back key app will be closed.